# Google+ People API returns Daily Limit error

Tags: google-plus

I get the following error

> Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup

when I am accessing the G+ People API. I don't see how I am not authenticated because I use the OAuth 2.0 credentials to make the api call.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How many requests are you having per day?
See: https://console.developers.google.com/project/____your_unique_google_plus_project_identifier____/apiui/apiview/plus?tabId=quotas

> Quota summary:
>
> - FREE QUOTA:  10,000 requests/day
> - PER USER LIMIT:  5 requests/second/user
>
> Sign-in Quota summary:
>
> - FREE QUOTA:  20,000,000 requests/day
> - PER USER LIMIT:  5 requests/second/user